# Lstm to improve tokenization

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, lstm

Recently I stared toying with tensor flow, dnns etc. now I'm trying to implement something more serious, information retrieval from short sentences (doctor instructions).
Unfortunately the dataset I have is, as always, quite "dirty". As I'm trying to use word embeddings, I actually need "clean" data. Take one example:
"Take two pilleach day". There is a missing white space between pill and each. I am implementing "tokenizer improver" to look at each sentence and propose new tokenization based on joint probability of each word in sentence given the frequency of terms in whole document (tf) . As I was doing it today, a thought came to my mind: why bother writing suboptimal solution for this problem when I can employ powerful learning algorithms such as Lstm networks  to do that for me. However, as of today, I have only a *feeling* that it's actually possible to do that. As we know, feelings are not best when it comes to architecting such complex problems. I don't know where to begin: what should be my training set and learning goal. 
I know this is a broad question, but I know there are many brilliant people with more knowledge about tensorflow and neural nets, so I'm sure that somebody has either already solved similar problem or just knows how to approach this problem.
Any guidance is welcome, I do not except you to solve this for me of course:)
Besos and all the best to all the tensorflow community:)

Comment: Text normalization is also a hard problem. From your example, is this something a spell check program can handle?

Comment: Only one that is context-aware in respect to my dataset. I have coded up solution that works quite well, will post as a proposed answer

Answer (score 2):

Having the same issue. I solved it by using a character level net. Basically I rewrote [Character-Aware Neural Language Models](https://github.com/carpedm20/lstm-char-cnn-tensorflow), kicked out the whole "words"-elements and just stayed with the caracter level.

Training Data: I took the data I had, as dirty as it was, used the dirty data as targets and made it even more dirty to create inputs.

So your "Take two pilleach day" will be learned as in many cases you do have a clean and similar phrase, e.g. "Take one pill each morning" that with the regime mentioned will serve as target and you train the net on destroyed inputs like "Take oe pileach mornin"

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this approach! For now, I just coded up a solution to find valid words inside of words recognized as spelling mistakes by pyenchant.checker.SpellCheck